# What would I be returning in this recursive method?

Tags: java, recursion, maze

```
public static int bombs(char[][] maze, int row, int col, ArrayList<int[]> checked, int bombs)
    {
        int size = maze.length;
        String value = Character.toString(maze[row][col]);
        if (value.equals("#"))//add one to bomb if it went through a wall
        {
            bombs = bombs+1;
        }
        if(row==size-1&&col==size-1)//if it has reached the end
        {
            return steps;
        }
        if(inBounds(row,col,size)) //if point is in bounds
        {
            if(!pointWasChecked(row,col,checked)) 
            {       //if point has not been checked
                checked.add(new int[]{row, col});
                
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
/*
. . # # #
. # . . #
# # # # #
# . # . .
# # # . .
example maze, this one's smallest path should be 2 bombs used
. is a path
# is a wall
/*
```

This is a recursive method that traverses through a maze and it uses a bomb when it gets to a wall but I want to return the smallest amount of bombs needed. I already know how to traverse the maze by calling the method again and doing row+1, row-1, col+1, col-1. I'm just confused on what I need to return so that I get to the end, don't end up returning zero, and return the smallest amount of bombs.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: A recursive method is a method that gets it's result by calling itself. What you posted above does not look like it uses recursion at al.

Answer (score 0):

Short version: return `Integer.MAX_VALUE` instead of zero.

Long version: Assuming `return steps` is actually `return bombs`, and you already know how to make the recursive calls:

If the current position is valid (in-bound, not yet checked and not the end) you will explore in all 4 directions.
After all four directions have been explored, you end up with 4 values (the number of steps after going in each direction). Then you return the smallest of each value.

If the current position is invalid, you have to return a value that is bigger than any correct value. The best bet for this is `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, which is the biggest value that can be coded on an integer.

Note that brute-force recursion can take rather long on large mazes, and cause Stack Overflows quite easily.